# Why is 'Options' disabled in Selenium IDE extension?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I need to set a timeout value to use for a "wait for" command, but the 'Options' box is disabled and i can't click on it. I'm using the Chrome extension, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Same here. Did you found the reason ?